# How can I use moment.js to format a date with vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

I use a [cdn](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment-with-locales.min.js) for `momentjs` and I try to format my date and time

```
    @{{ process_photo.created_at.moment().format("Do MMM YYYY") }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `momentjs` in the template, you'd have to use it indirectly through a component [method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods). For example, you could declare a `formatDate` method that returns the `moment.format()` results, and use `formatDate` in the template:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      process_photo: {
        created_at: new Date()
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    formatDate(date) {
      return moment(date).format("Do MMM YYYY")
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11">
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.26.0/moment.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>@{{ formatDate(process_photo.created_at) }}</p>
</div>
```